# "Copy location with parameters" for Google Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, firebug

Is there a way in Google Chrome Developer tools to copy an AJAX request with the parameters? Firebug has this feature to "Copy location with parameters" for any async request and it is extremely useful.

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those still looking after all these years, Chrome's "Replay XHR" is as close as you get.

Debugger -> Network -> XHR -> right-click on request -> Replay XHR

The output can be seen in "Response" tab when you click on the new replayed request. If someone else finds a way to neatly copy all the post parameters like Firebug, let me know.

(Alternatively, I believe you can also install [Firebug for Chrome](https://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/))

Answer (score 0):

In version 26 of google chrome the "copy as cURL" feature was added:

https://coderwall.com/p/-fdgoq

If you are testing GET methods you can just right click on a request in the network tab and click "open in new tab", every time you refresh that tab you will resend the request. Unfortunately you can't resubmit POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

When your page gets load perform the following actions:

Right click on the page --> select "Inspect Element" -- > Slect the "Network tab" from the window that gets opened --> you will see all the ajax and jquery calls

Answer (score 0):

copy paste this code in Inspent Element **Console** to GET AJAX information...

```
var ajaxArgs = [];
(function($){
    // backup ajax request
    $.ajaxBefore = $.ajax;
    // rewrite ajax function 
    $.ajax = function (a){ajaxArgs.push(a); return $.ajaxBefore(a)}
})(typeof jQuery == 'undefined' ? $ :  jQuery );
```

After Ajax Send Requeest You Can type `ajaxArgs` or `console.log(ajaxArgs);` in Inspect Element to See All Args.. Good Luck and Use it for **Good reason**